# HTML Text input field different width to others in the same class

Tags: html, css

Sorry if the title isn't clear, I couldn't think of a shorter way of stating it without taking away to much.

Now, I have made a simple contact form (currently doesn't submit etc) with 4 labels and 4 text inputs. Each pair is contained inside it's own div and then styled by class.

Everything lines up and is where I want it, except the 4th div is off. The text field is one pixel wider than the rest, which also bumps the label out of alignment.

Here's what I've got...

HTML:

```
<div id="contact-form">
  <div id="form-title">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <h5>Enter your details below to contact me</h5>
  </div>

  <form id="contact">
    <div class="input">
      <label>First name:
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" />
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      As above, "Surname" 
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      As above, "Phone" 
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      As above, "Email" 
    </div>

  </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.input {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.input label {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding:0;
}

.input input {
    width:60%;
    margin:0 5px 0 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:right;
}
```

Here's how it displays

```
Title... 

First name:  [text] 
   Surname:  [text]
     Phone:  [text] 
    Email:  [text ]
```

I've been through all the other code and nothing should be interacting with this section at all.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated, also please note that I've searched and tried and tested so the way that it's styled may not be the best or most efficient.

**EDIT:**
Here's the full code of the section.

HTML:

```
<div id="contact-form">
  <div id="form-title">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <h5>Enter your details below to contact me.</h5>
  </div>

  <form id="contact">
    <div class="input">
      <label>First name
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="John" />
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Surname:
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="Smith />
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Phone
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="0412345678" />
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Email
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="j.smith@example.com" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a fiddle.

Comment: Do you have a "space" in the html code betwin label & input ?
with inline-block, you can have a 3px offset.
Please give your full HTML code

Comment: Each input is embedded inside the label, there is no blank spaces, just the new line for ease of reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through trial and error I have found a way to make it work properly.

Here's the updated html:

```
<div id="contact-form">
  <div id="form-title">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <h5>Enter your details below to contact me.</h5>
  </div>

  <form id="contact">
    <div class="input">
      <label>First name:</label>
      <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="John" />
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Surname:</label>
      <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="Smith" />
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Phone:</label>
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="0412345678" />
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Email:</label>
      <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="j.smith@example.com" />
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

And the update css:

```
.input {
width:100%;
}

.input label {
    width:35%;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding:0;
    padding-top:5px;
}

.txt-box {
    width:50%;
    margin:0;
    margin-left:3px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:right;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this css

```css
.input {
    width:100%;
    display:inline-block;
}

.input label {
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:left;
    text-align:right;
    padding:0;
    width:45%;
}

.input input {
    width:55%;
    margin:0 5px 0 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="contact-form">
  <div id="form-title">
    <h3>Contact Form</h3>
    <h5>Enter your details below to contact me.</h5>
  </div>

  <form id="contact">
    <div class="input">
      <label>First name:
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="John" />
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Surname:
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="Smith" />
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Phone:
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="0412345678" />
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="input">
      <label>Email:
        <input class="txt-box" type="text" placeholder="j.smith@example.com" />
      </label>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

[jsfiddle output](https://jsfiddle.net/62zejLL2/3/)

Comment: This displays the input field underneath the label.

Comment: have you checked the jsfiddle output? @mrkd1991

Comment: i have made some changes in above snippet. i hope it may helps you. @mrkd1991

Comment: This works also, very similar to what I ended up coming up with. Thanks for your help.